# How to store a simple key string inside Java KeyStore?

Tags: java, keystore

I have a file on my FS (a S3 AWS key) that contains a string that is a key I use for encryption process.

I would like to move it a Java KeyStore.

I know how to import a certificate into a KeyStore with keytool but I can't find the way to import a simple string key.

Can you help?

Comment: Just a heads up for future questions: if you add the `java` tag for your java questions you'll get a lot more people seeing them.

Comment: oh! I didn't realized that people are searching questions by tags.. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a way to do it with keytool, but some poking about, I wonder if you could store and retrieve it in code as a PasswordBasedEncryption (PBE) SecretKey. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself).

The resources that drove this thought:
[PBEKeySpec javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html) and [CryptoSpec - Using Password Based Encryption example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#PBEEx)

Comment: See my answer - you can with PBE. I provided code. JCEKS will let you store a string as a key in a keystore.

Comment: I'll just add that it is recommended to use PKCS12 instead of JCEKS, see my answer below.

Answer (score 16):

I had to do this this afternoon, the solution of @JasonG works but not the keytool options.

Since Java 8 you can use the `-importpass` option with Keytool, which will help you achieve what you need.

Let's suppose I want to save the sensitive password `foobar` in the `mypass` alias in the keystore named `myks.jceks` protected with the password `password` here, do the following:

```
$ keytool -importpass -storetype pkcs12 -alias mypass -keystore myks.p12
Enter keystore password: <password>
Re-enter new password: <password>
Enter the password to be stored: <foobar>
Re-enter password: <foobar>
Enter key password for <mypass>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password): <password>
Re-enter new password: <password>
```

And then you're good to go to use the same code as @JasonG, I have this in my code:

```
private Try<String> loadKey(Resource path, String pw) {
    return Try.of(() -> {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(path.getInputStream(), pw.toCharArray());

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBE");
        SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("mypass",
                new PasswordProtection(pw.toCharArray()));

        PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec) factory.getKeySpec(
                ske.getSecretKey(), PBEKeySpec.class);

        return new String(keySpec.getPassword());
    });
}
```

Note that I have used PKCS12 since JCEKS uses a proprietary format, and it is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format.

Besides we had some problems with some Windows machine (running Java 8) being stuck while trying to load the JCEKS store, throwing exceptions. PKCS12 seems a better choice.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with PBE and JCEKS. I don't think you can do it with JKS.
Solution:

Create a keystore to store and get entries from:

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client -storetype jceks
```

Now some code to test it out.

```
   public static String getPasswordFromKeystore(String entry, String keystoreLocation, String keyStorePassword) throws Exception{

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        ks.load(null, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreLocation);

        ks.load(fIn, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBE");

        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske =
                (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)ks.getEntry(entry, keyStorePP);

        PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(
                ske.getSecretKey(),
                PBEKeySpec.class);

        char[] password = keySpec.getPassword();

        return new String(password);

    }

    public static void makeNewKeystoreEntry(String entry, String entryPassword, String keyStoreLocation, String keyStorePassword)
            throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBE");
        SecretKey generatedSecret =
                factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(
                        entryPassword.toCharArray()));

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        ks.load(null, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        ks.setEntry(entry, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(
                generatedSecret), keyStorePP);

        FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(keyStoreLocation);
        ks.store(fos, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    }
```

Comment: Only thing that stinks about this is the fact that you still expose your keystore password.  Would have to be stored in an environment variable or something that's user specific.

Comment: @JasonG : Is there any limit on the length of the stored password? E.g. if you use a 128bit secret key to store the password, can it contain a longer password?

Comment: @dardo you can either have the user remember the password or save it somewhere. It's a shame that OS's do not provide a way to only expose the password to your program.

Comment: `keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: clientkeystore (Access denied)` is what I get. Keystores are complicated and I still haven't found a single answer that works.

Comment: We are using a solution like this in multiple areas now to protect passwords in the env.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old; but I came across this same use case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/keytool.htm#JSWOR-GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549

keystores have an importpass options that stores a KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry identified by alias.

So there's that and you could store your string in an alias.

Answer (score -3):

You can not import in the key store arbitrary strings. In the key store you import certification keys that java libraries are using for authentication of remote hosts.

Comment: In fact you can, as @Charlie described in his answer above