# Add ssh private key to a java keystore

Tags: java, ssh, keystore, jks

There have seen a number of similar question,but none exactly like mine. The given answers have not worked for me. 
I wanted to add a private ssh key to a java keystore in command line and later retrive it in java code.

I have generated the ssh keys in the following way :

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "abc@xyz.com"`

That gives me 2 key file. 'id_rsa' and 'id_rsa.pub' i.e the public and private key

I want to store just the private key i.e. 'id_rsa' into the java keystore using the keytool command line tool.

I am trying something like this.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key  -in key.pub -out identity.p12 -name alias1 -nocerts

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass "password1" -destkeypass "password2" -destkeystore ~/jks/keystore1.jks -srckeystore /tmp/keys/identity.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass "pass" -alias "alias1"
```

But that gives me 'keytool error: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input'

Please guide me on the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385944/how-to-add-ssh-identity-file-keypair-to-jks-keystore

Comment: I have already seen that, but in that solution, I do not know where the example.req comes from ?  It says to do something like :                             openssl x509 -signkey id_rsa -req -in example.req

Comment: Looks like he created a certificate prior to that, and used that to wrap the ssh key.  He just skipped the steps prior to that.  Here's a site that shows you the Certificate Signing Request steps, https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will try this.