# getting sometimes "Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I just use SSL connections in my android project and it works fine but sometimes I get this error:

```
HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    ... 36 more
```

as you can see it says that it cannot found my certificate but it happens sometimes not all the time.
my certificate is not a self-certificate type.
can anyone help me with that

Comment: Have you added certificate in your keystore ?

Comment: no, actually I don't have the keystore either. should I use keystore even when I use nonself generated certificates

Comment: When I was doing same thing, I transfer my own certificate in keystore and it worked fine

Comment: do you have any sample code?

Comment: code ?????? you need a command to transfer certificate in keystore, not a code.

Comment: I'm sorry :) sample command .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31385944/996493